# Python/Selenium How to select first option of autocomplete searchbar

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to enter a keyword into a searchbar of [this site](https://confluence.eits.uga.edu/dashboard.action) and select the first autocomplete option that comes up. If I were to do this manually I would type in "remote" in the search bar and press the downkey and press enter which I have tried to replicate in my code below, but instead it seems to be skipping the downkey part and not selecting the first autocomplete option and going to the search results page instead of [this page](https://confluence.eits.uga.edu/display/HDSH/Remote+Access+VPN) which is the first autocomplete option.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://confluence.eits.uga.edu/dashboard.action")

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("quick-search-query")
elem.send_keys("remote")
elem.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Anyone have any ideas why the downkey is not being registered or am I not using the right syntax?

Comment: have you tried `elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` instead of `elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`?

Comment: Both `ENTER` and `RETURN` works for me. Which selenium, chrome and chromedriver versions are you using?

Comment: @alecxe I installed selenium doing $pip3 install selenium so I assume the latest one and I am using chromedriver version 2.29

Comment: @JohnSmith what if you add `time.sleep(5)` after sending `remote` and before sending "arrow down"? (don't forget to import `time`)

Comment: @kushal. that didn't make a difference for me. Also if you guys are testing this are you able to replicate the problem I'm having or is this just me?

Comment: @alecxe hm it still produced the same result of going to the results page instead of actually selecting the first autocomplete option

Comment: ah, I think I got what your problem is about, was solving a different problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are still sending the keys to the search input that triggers the search. Instead, find the first quick search dropdown option and send keys to it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://confluence.eits.uga.edu/dashboard.action")

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("quick-search-query")
elem.send_keys("remote")
elem.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)

# wait for the first dropdown option to appear and open it
first_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".quick-search-dropdown li a")))
first_option.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Use Keys.ARROW_DOWN is a perfect approach! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also try actionchains in this case as following:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("quick-search-query")
elem.send_keys("remote")

suggestion = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#quick-search > fieldset > div > div > ol:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(1) a > span")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(suggestion )
actions.click(suggestion)
actions.perform()
```